# Stop Safari/Firefox from Cacheing my page

Tags: firefox, caching, safari, webkit, page-refresh

I'm using PHP(header) to send a user back to the home page of the website(which looks different, due to a cookie, then when the user first arrived).

Everything works fine in Google Chrome but in Safari and FireFox a cached version of index.php is shown instead of the updated version of the webpage.

If I hit refresh things look as they should, but I need a way to tell the browser to reload the page without the user having to hit refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
http://smartcoding.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/php-force-no-cache-page-load/

Comment: Thought it worked for a second but I was in Chrome. I don't see how browser cache could be turned off with PHP if it doesn't convert into any front-end code.

Comment: Have you tried `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`?

Comment: I hadn't, you would think that would do it but, no effect.

Comment: After you add it, don't forget to force-refresh so that it actually takes effect, otherwise you're still looking at the same cache version.